# invalid : syntax of callback URL is incorrect. sample callback URL is as 'https://merchant.com/calback/ in paytm integration React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, callback, checksum, paytm

I am trying to implement Paytm integration in react native. but I am getting this error = "invalid : syntax of callback URL is incorrect. sample callback URL is as 'https://merchant.com/calback/". please tell me whats wrong with my code

here is my code

```
call_api = () => {
    fetch("https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },

      body: JSON.stringify([
        {
          mobile_no: "XXXXXx",
          user_id: "XX",
          patient_name: "XXXx",
        },
      ]),
    })
      .then((returnValue) => returnValue.json())

      .then((response) => {
        console.log("this checksum api esponse" + JSON.stringify(response));

        this.setState({ order_id: response[0].data.order_id });
        this.setState({ checksum: response[0].data.checksumhash });

        this.pay();
      });
  };



  pay = () => {
    const details = {
      // mode: "Staging", // 'Staging' or 'Production'
      mode: "Production",
      MID: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID: "Retail",
      WEBSITE: "APPSTAGING",
      CHANNEL_ID: "WAP",
      TXN_AMOUNT: "1", // String
      ORDER_ID: this.state.order_id, // String
      // EMAIL: email, // String
      // MOBILE_NO: mobile, // String
      CUST_ID: "CUSTOMER_1", // String
      CHECKSUMHASH: `${this.state.checksum}`, //From your server using PayTM Checksum Utility
      // CALLBACK_URL:
      //   "https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=" +
      //   `${this.state.order_id}`,
      CALLBACK_URL: `https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=<${this.state.order_id}>`,
    };
    Paytm.startPayment(details);
    console.log(details);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

In callbackUrl param, you need to pass your website URL where you want to get the response. If you don't have your own callback Url, you can use Paytm's static callback URL which is mentioned in the documentation of react native on Developer Portal. It should be same as you have sent in your **const details**